# Gradle - Oracle XE -No suitable driver Found

Tags: java, oracle, gradle, groovy

docker-compose

```
  oracle:
    image: quillbuilduser/oracle-18-xe-micro-sq
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
    # Opatch is an internal java-based daemon in the Oracle container that updates components, don't really need it here. Reduce it's memory settings.
    environment:
      - OPATCH_JRE_MEMORY_OPTIONS=-Xms128m -Xmx256m -XX:PermSize=16m -XX:MaxPermSize=32m -Xss1m
```

gradle.build

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayCleanTask
import org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '6.0.8'
}

task createFlywayUser(){
    Sql sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE', 'mysecretuser', 'mysecretpassword')
    try {
        sql.execute("""
                DO \$\$
                BEGIN
                  CREATE USER flyway
                  IDENTIFIED BY $project.ext.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
                  DEFAULT TABLESPACE system
                  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
                  QUOTA 20M on system;
                  
                  GRANT DBA TO flyway;
                END
                \$\$;            
            """.toString())
    } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore */ }
    finally {
        sql.close()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to start an oracle db for testing and as in production I would like to use flyway to do the migrations. So I wanted to create the flyway user as a groovy task but with the code above I always get the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE
```

so I've tried a few variations for creating the sql.newInstance for example adding the driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver as the last param, or removing the // after the @. But I can't seem to find the right combination. Or adding `Sql.loadDriver('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')`.

I've managed to connect to the db using dbeaver and I can see its using the ojdbc8:12.2.0.1 driver. (I was originally using the 21.1.0.0)

I'll also accept a better way to create the user instead of using the gradle task if you have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
configurations {
    jdbcdriver
}

dependencies {
    jdbcdriver 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1'
}

task createFlywayUser(){
    doLast {
        configurations.jdbcdriver.files.each {
            Sql.classLoader.addURL(it.toURI().toURL())
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Solves it. But is a massive hack